# CSS 'background-attribute: fixed' but for image

Tags: css, wordpress, image, scroll, background

I want to edit a Wordpress site using the theme's CSS, I want to make the header image fixed when scrolled but the problem is that the header is not a background image, but a picture.

I know if I can do this for a background image:

```
.homeBG {
    background-image: url('someImage.jpg');
    background-attribute: fixed;
}
```

But what command would you use if this is the case:

```
.homeBG {
    content: url('someImage.jpg');
    /*make the image stay when scrolled*/
}
```

Note: changing "content" to "background-image" would not work for the theme I am using.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `position:fixed;`

**Change:**

```
.homeBG {
    content: url('someImage.jpg');
}
```

**To:**

```
.homeBG {
    content: url('someImage.jpg');
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

It's important to note that when using `top:0px;` `left:0px;` or alternatively `right:0px;` to position elements via `position:fixed;` that their position will be fixed relative to the entire browser window. You may need to adjust the `z-index` of `.homeBG` if it becomes fixed over top of other elements.

**More information on `position`**

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/